# Define column in android tableLayout in java code

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am using tablelayout in java file with 7 row and 7 column. In the first row i have three button which i want to place in 2nd, 4th and 6th column. The third button will span the column with 7th column. How can i define the column in java file and span the column. Next 6 row and 7 column contain 42 buttons.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `column` and `span`.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams trParam = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
trParam.column= 6
trParam.span = 5;

TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TextView content = new TextView(this);
content.setLayoutParams(trParam);
content.addView(title);
```

I learned this from [here](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-%E2%80%93-layouts-part-two-table-and-absolute-layouts/) if you want further info on TableLayouts.